# excel with an SAS engine

Tags: excel, vba, statistics, sas

is it possible to run excel with an SAS engine and run SAS code on it?

the purpose of this i want to learn SAS a little bit and i dont want to buy it, so maybe i could use it through excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sas Base is a very easy to learn lenguage.. I think is more important to learn about data modeling ETL Reporting Data Mining etc before to learn SAS I work with SAS in my actual job and SAS base is a repetitive language as COBOL i mean is not an all purpose language is not as big as java is.

Answer (score 7):

No, Excel has no built-in support for running SAS code. However, SAS does have an [Office Add-in](http://www.sas.com/technologies/bi/msoffice/) that allows you to interact with SAS from Excel. However, you are required to have licensed SAS to use this.

Answer (score 4):

For learning purposes, check out the ["Learning Edition"](http://support.sas.com/learn/le/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

**As far as know，The SAS9.3 version has a add-in for Microsoft Excel which can interact with the SAS.
It provides many functions about SAS. I think it's powerful.**

Answer (score 1):

If yo are fortunate enough to have access to a *nix system (such as Linux or one of the BSD's), you could take a look at [DAP](http://www.gnu.org/software/dap/dap.html), an open source statistics package that should be able to run this type of programs.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, YES - you CAN use Excel to run SAS code - using the IOM & VBA.  It is possible to have a code window, log window and results window within Excel, effectively emulating BASE SAS (we did this in our office).
However:

- You need the SAS Addin for Microsoft Office installed
- You need a connection to a SAS session (local or remote).

So prob doesn't suit your purposes.  But it can be (and has been) done!